# Ember.TextField : Access to jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

my first post on stackoverflow. (and english is not my native tongue).

I am trying to learn how to use emberjs.
It's not easy because of the lack of good tutorials.

So I decided to code a chat, I use nodejs and socket.io server-side.

Html

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class="page">

    <div class="users">
    </div>

    <div class="messagebox">
        {{#view App.TextField valueBinding="currentMsg" placeholder="your message"}}{{/view}}

        <button {{action "sendMsg"}}>Send</button>
    </div>

    <div id="chatbox">
    {{#collection contentBinding="App.MsgsController" tagName="ul"}}
        <b>{{value}}</b>
    {{/collection}}
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Javascript

```js
var id;

var socketio = io.connect("127.0.0.1:8888");
socketio.on('id', function (data) {
    id = data;
});
socketio.on("broadcast", function (data) {
    if (id == data.id) {
        return
    }
    App.MsgsController.addMsg(data.message);

});
socketio.on("own", function (data) {
    App.MsgsController.addMsg(data.message);
});



App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Msg = Ember.Object.extend({
    value: null
});

App.MsgsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    addMsg: function (value) {
        var msg = App.Msg.create({
            value: value
        });
        this.pushObject(msg);
    }
});

App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    insertNewline: function() {
        this.get("controller").send("sendMsg");
    }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    currentMsg: 't',
    sendMsg: function () {
        var currentMsg = this.get('currentMsg');
        if(currentMsg) {
            socketio.emit("message", { message: currentMsg, id: id});
            this.set('currentMsg', '');
        }
    }
});
```

I want to focus App.TextField after the App.ApplicationController.sendMsg call.

I tried

```js
App.TextField.$().focus()
```

but it seems that I can only use $() inside of its methods.

Someone can help me, please?

Edit : 
Ok, I found the answer.

App.TextField is like "class", and the one on the view is an instance.

I must add an id in my view

```
{{#view App.TextField valueBinding="currentMsg" placeholder="your message" id="mytextfield"}}{{/view}}
```

and use jquery selector to access to the instance

```
$('#mytextfield').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use didInsertElement hook for the view to handle jquery methods.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement